# How to use calendar in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, calendar

I am stuck on a website where Ive to use dates with a calendar widget.
The dates cannot be typed it can only be selected using the calendar widget.
I need to select the "start date" and the "end date" from the calendar widget.
How do I go about this??

I have tried using the `sendKeys()` method in selenium but that does not work as I cannot type in the entry box

Comment: I wrote an answer. Comment if it's not working and mention the issue.

Comment: Can you share the url if's possible.

Comment: @supputuri
 You cannot access the url. The calendar is only thing, I cannot type the date using send keys that is the problem. the widget has next button for moving months and dates

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar situation a few days back and this is what I've done.

First, get the `Webelement` of the date input field.

Second, make the driver click `Ctrl + A`(Select All).

Third, use `sendKeys()` to put the required date in the input field.

Then make the driver click on the `Enter` button.

This is the code I'd used in `C#`. I'm sure, it'll be similar to this in `Python`.

```
IWebElement webelem1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="dp1562561797092"]")); //get the iwebelement of input field
webelem1.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a"); // click on Ctrl+A
webelem1.SendKeys("1/1/2019"); // Send required date
webelem1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); //Click on Enter
```

Comment: I cannot type the date in the date input field it always opens the calendar widget, so I am not sure if send_keys() option would work, would it? The calendar element has input name , type , class, autocomplete and readonly

Comment: @ShernelMonteiro 
get the input field
You'll have something like this : <input type = "text" ...........
get the XPath of that element.
It'll work. It worked for me. I too faced the exact same issue.

Comment: @ShernelMonteiro
If possible put a screenshot so that I can understand.

Comment: You sure this XPath matches only with this one text box? What error are you getting? Give the exact error?

Comment: It just selects the date box, selects date inside it? but doesn't modify it?